# How to add scrolling to 2D platformed in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I know there are threads about this but I don't understand them and the people already have a camera class and stuff and I have no idea what some of the stuff means.

So, how do I make it so the game scrolls and follows my player? I will post my code if you need. But I just need to know how to make a "camera" class to make it look like it's scrolling.

My game is **800x600**. I will post the code if you need me to but I don't think its needed.

I need it explained to see I can make it on my own and not just copy and not learn from it

My character is 112x112.

Answer (score 1):

Well the first thing to understand is that everything do-able with a class is do-able without a class. Classes just add abstraction and make it easier to keep track of what objects are in charge of which functions. For example, here is one way you could keep track of your player.

```
playerRect = pygame.rect(x, y, w, h)
playerImg = pygame.image.load("file/path/player.png")
#playerHealth, items, and other variables
```

Here is the OOP (object-oriented programming) way to do it:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, rect, pathToImg, otherVariables):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(pathToImg)
        self.otherThings = otherVariables
```

Functionally, both of these work. So why is the second way better? If we want to draw the player on the screen, and we are storing the player the first way, here is what we would do:

```
mainWindow.blit(playerImg, playerRect)
```

This isn't too bad, but it could be a lot neater. This way, we have to keep track of two different variables and remember the order of the arguments. With the OOP method, we can just keep track of the player object and tell it to draw itself, and it will take care of the little details for us. For example:

```
class Player:
    def __init__ #....
    #...
    def draw(window):
        window.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Now to draw the player on screen, we just call

```
player.draw(mainWindow)
```

This is a silly example since it's not very complicated to blit your player to the screen. But imagine something more complicated. What if you want to know if your player is able to purchase an item from an NPC in your game? You'll need to pass in `playerCoins, playerFreeSpaceInInventory, itemIsUnlocked, itemCost, NPCItemList` and possibly others. If you design your game with OOP in mind, you will instead just pass in the player object, the npc object and the item. That is much easier to understand.

---

Now, onto scrolling. The basic idea for scrolling is that you blit the images with an offset to where they actually are. So if you have a rect at `400, 300`, but you have moved the camera down and to the right by 100 pixels each, you will actually draw the rect at `300, 200`. Without a class, you would do that somewhat like this:

```
cameraX = 0
cameraY = 0
```

Then update **all** of your draw (or blit) calls to look like this

```
mainWindow.blit(playerImg, (playerRect.x - cameraX, playerRect.y - cameraY))
```

Now the only thing we're missing is updating the camera X and Y when the player moves offscreen.

```
#It's a while since I've written this, so my logic might be slightly off but you get the idea
def updateCamera(playerRect):
    if playerRect.right - cameraX > windowWidth:
        cameraX += (playerRect.right - cameraX - windowWidth) 
    if playerRect.left - cameraX < 0:
        cameraX -= (playerRect.left - cameraX)
    #same as above but for vertical position
```

There are some ways we could simplify this. If we keep cameraX and cameraY in a rect instead, it would make updating the position simpler.

```
def updateCamera(playerRect, camera):
    if playerRect.right - camera.x > windowWidth:
        camera.right = playerRect.right
    if playerRect.left - camera.x < 0:
        camera.left = playerRect.left
    #same as above but for vertical position
```

It is worth noting that this will only move the camera when the player is at the very edge of the screen. The downside to this is that the player cannot see in front of them, and might walk right into an enemy that was just offscreen. To have the player stay more towards the middle, you'll want an inner rect. If the on screen position of the player (the absolute position minus the camera offset) moves outside this inner rect, the camera offset will grow or shrink to bring the screen position back inside of the inner rect. This inner rect will stay in the same spot on the screen even if the outerCamera updates its position

Now that's all you need for a functioning camera even without using a class. If you want to wrap this up in a class (which I recommend), you just take each property or function of the camera and add it to your new class. For example, the updateCamera makes sense inside of your class, as well as the cameraRect. The next step after that would be to have your camera class inherit from pygame.rect, so that you can call `camera.x` rather than `camera.rect.x` However, if you have not worked with classes before, start small. Take a python OOP tutorial. Then try making a player class that has the same functionality as your current player. Then you're ready to make a camera class.